# Writing a character array to a file in C (given methods dont work)

Tags: c, file-io

I am trying to copy a character array to a text file, but it refuses to be copied. I have added a sample text to be written, which works wine, so probably the problem is with the array `payload[256]`?
(`char payload[256]` is the array i am trying to copy):

```
printf("new value of payload-----> \n");

for (int x2 = 0; x2 < 256; x2++)  //PRINTING THE ARRAY. IT IS FILLED UP
{
    printf("%x",payload[x2]);
    //if ((x2 + 1) % 16 == 0) printf("\n");
}
getchar();

FILE *fptr= fopen("program.txt", "w");
if (fptr == NULL)
{
    printf("Error!");
    exit(1);
}
const char*p = payload;

fprintf(fptr, "%s", p);            //DOESNT PRINT
fprintf(fptr, "%s", &payload[0]);  //DOESNT PRINT
fprintf(fptr, "%s", payload);      //DOESNT PRINT

const char *text = "Write this to the file";
fprintf(fptr, "Some text: %s\n", text);   //WORKS FINE

int results = fputs(payload, fptr); //DOESNT WORK

fclose(fptr);
```

Please help.

Comment: `payload` ends with '\0' ???

Comment: sorry didn't get your question

Comment: i was just trying to demonstrate that neither of the 3 or 4 permutations are working for me @pynchia

Comment: what @Jeyaram meant is, `%s` expects a pointer to the first element of a null-terminated `char` array. If the array is not-null terminated, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: please take some time to learn pointers. AVOID writing awful things like `&payload[0]` (write `payload` instead!)

Comment: then no, it is not null terminated. but shouldn't fputs work at least?

Comment: I'd bet that `payload[0] == 0` in you case. So you are writing an empty string.

Comment: payload[0] will be `(null)`

Comment: I added  payload[255] = '\0';
it doesn't work

Comment: @Jeyaram NULL is a Pointer....

Comment: yes payload[0]=0
but the rest of the string is filled @marian

Comment: Then that's your problem.  The string starts with a NULL byte, so it's an empty string.  Anything else that comes after doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `fprintf(fptr, "%s", p);`, try this:

```
for (int x2 = 0; x2 < 256; x2++)  
      {
          fprintf(fptr,"%x",payload[x2]);
      }
```

As other have stated, %s is used for NULL-terminated strings of displayable characters. It sounds like you don't have that.

Answer (score 0):

insert this line before trying to print:

```
payload[255] = '\0';
```

and be sure there is no '\0' anywhere earlier in the payload[] array.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print three strings (%S) to the file. What does payload contain? Printable characters?

Therefore you need to make sure that it's printable characters and null terminated.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably need is the function `fwrite`. Try:

```
int results = fwrite(payload, sizeof(payload), 1, fptr);
```